# Windows Device Emulator V3, windows 7 + Network

Tags: .net, windows-7, windows-ce

Well im debugging a windows CE application from visual studio in the Windows Device Emulator, now to setup the network i go to File -> Configure -> Network, i enable a network card and press OK, then i get this message:

**"The required Virtual Machine Network Driver could not be found. Make sure that Virtual PC 2007 is installed. You can install Virtual PC 2007 from  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=46859"**

Im running windows 7 and got a built-in Virtual pc and i would rather not have 2 installed at the same time is there any way to get this network driver without installing virtual PC 2007?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if any one else gets this problem here is the solution:

http://brianpeek.com/post/windows-virtual-pc-and-the-microsoft-device-emulator

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm it works on Windows 8.1 for a Windows Mobile 5.0 emulator! Though it would be nice to copy the relevant instructions over from the link you posted into your answer. Links can often break, as is the case with many "answers" I've found here on SO earlier. (and a question answered with a 404 link is worse than a question without any answer)

Answer (score 0):

Just an addendum to Petoj's answer: the virtual PC drivers do not require Windows 7 - his answer is just as applicable to Windows XP.